# class definition in DOM connect in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, dom

I don't know what is different between **(I)** and **(II)** ?
whether these class is same for use in a (js file/css file) or not 
different ?

`I: <div class="start-box active">`

`II: <div class="start-box">`

Answer (score 0):

in I you have two class **start-box** and **active** but in II you have just one class.
you can use js to add or delete class from element. and with css you can set some css property for the active when use event handler
you can read this link [HTML Event Attributes](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_eventattributes.asp)

Answer (score 0):

The `class` name attribute of an element accepts a single class name, or a space separated list of class names.

So in

```
<div class="start-box active">
```

the `div` element has two classes, `start-box` and `active`, whereas in

```
<div class="start-box">
```

the `div` element is only assigned the one class, `start-box`.

The combination of multiple classes on one element, or even the effect of a single class on an element given its relationship to other elements, is subject to the rules of cascading style sheets (meaning "CSS") .

I wish you well in learning more about CSS - you may find that the article "Learn to style HTML using CSS"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS) on MDN useful in doing so.